# java.sql.SQLException: Missing IN or OUT parameter at index::4 error occurs with preparestatement

Tags: java, parameters, prepared-statement

```
strInsertQuery="INSERT INTO SYNPACKAGEFREEUSAGEMAPPING (PACKAGEID,SERVICEID,PRIORITY,MAPPINGID,ATTRIBUTEVALUE,FREEUSAGE,UOM,PARAMSTR1,UNITCREDITPOLICYDETAILID) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
newPstmt=newCon.prepareStatement(strInsertQuery);
newPstmt.setString(1,strProductId);
              newPstmt.setString(2,strUPGServiceId);
              newPstmt.setInt(3,0);
              if(FieldMappingrs.next())
              {
               newPstmt.setLong(4,FieldMappingrs.getLong(1));
              }
              newPstmt.setString(5,ucpDetailData.getCreditattributevalue());
              for(Iterator itrColUnitCreditDetail=ucpData.iterator();itrColUnitCreditDetail.hasNext();)
       {

        unitCreditData = (UnitCreditDetailData)itrColUnitCreditDetail.next();
        if(ucpDetailData.getUnitcreditpolicydetailid().equals(unitCreditData.getUnitcreditpolicydetailid()))
        {
         debugLog(PackageConstant.PACKAGE_MODULE_NAME,"ServicePackageSessionBean:createFreeUsageServiceDetails() unitCreditData "+ unitCreditData);
                newPstmt.setDouble(6,unitCreditData.getEndvalue());
               }

               debugLog(PackageConstant.PACKAGE_MODULE_NAME,"Insert record successfull"+ ucpDetailData);
              }
              newPstmt.setString(7,ucpDetailData.getUom());
              newPstmt.setString(8,ucpDetailData.getCreditattribute());
              newPstmt.setString(9,ucpDetailData.getUnitcreditpolicydetailid());

              newPstmt.executeUpdate();
```

Answer (score 5):

Well, look at this:

```
if(FieldMappingrs.next())
{
    newPstmt.setLong(4,FieldMappingrs.getLong(1));
}
```

So you're *conditionally* setting parameter 4.

What do you want to insert if `FieldMappingsrs.next()` returns false? (I suspect this is what is happening.) Try setting it to an appropriate value in an `else` block.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is just at this block

```
  if(FieldMappingrs.next()) {
      newPstmt.setLong(4,FieldMappingrs.getLong(1));
  }
```

As you see if `.next()` returns `false` you won't be passing the parameter at `index` 4.

I suggest to, if you can pass to that table 0 instead of null use this

```
  if(FieldMappingrs.next()) {
      newPstmt.setLong(4,FieldMappingrs.getLong(1));
  } else {
      newPstmt.setLong(4,0);
  }
```

Or if it is required value, just throw an `exception`.